# Xpath error when using .innertext in vb

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I wrote this piece of code in order to get the html code from a URL inserted by the user.
I used the HtmlAgilityPack because i want to work with only specific parts of the code(body,title etc). I succeeded "downloading" the data from the website but i geuss my Xpath code is somehow incorrect.
Here is the relevent code:

```
Dim htmlWeb As String = URL (inserted by the user)
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlWeb)
Dim htmlText As String
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = True
Dim myBR As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("...")
    htmlText = myBR("...").InnerText

    For Each Match_Positive_Word As Match In Regex.Matches(htmlText, Positive_Words)
        Positive_Counter = Positive_Counter + 1
    Next

    For Each Match_Negative_Word As Match In Regex.Matches(htmlText, Negative_Words)
        Negative_Counter = Negative_Counter + 1
    Next
```

Questions:

- What i need to write inside the brackets in order to get, for instance, the data inside the body tag?
- Does my connection with the html code is correct? Is there any better or more efficient way to do this?

**EDIT**

When i do `htmlDoc.Load(htmlWeb)` it gives me the error: URI formats are not supported.But when i do LoadHtml it seems to work. The main problem is in the line
  `htmlText = myBR.InnerText.` it returns the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Here is what i wrote:

```
Dim htmlWeb As String = URL
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlWeb)
Dim htmlText As String
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = True
Dim myBR As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")
    htmlText = myBR().InnerText
```

Is there anything i need to add in the barackets of myBR?
I tried .InnerHtml and it doesn't work either.

Comment: tried a simple wiki url - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

Comment: okay, updated my answer. Turned out `HtmlDocument`'s `Load()` method doesn't support loading xml from web URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Use `Load()` method if you have the URL, and use `LoadHtml()` if you have the html page. It appears that you need the first method in this case :</s>

```
htmlDoc.Load(htmlWeb)
```

As you asked as an example, to get body tag you can use this simple XPath `//body`

**UPDATE :**

I missed the fact that HAP's `HtmlDocument`, unlike `XDocument`, can't `Load` directly from URL. The method only accept path to a file in local machine. To load `HtmlDocument` from URL you need to use `HtmlWeb`'s `Load()` method instead. Try this way :

```
Dim htmlWeb As New HtmlWeb
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(URL)
Dim htmlText As String
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = True
Dim myBR As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")
    htmlText = myBR().InnerText
```